impossible to add element into a list in swift
I am trying to build a list of View based on a list of Strings but xcode still complain about: No exact matches in reference to static method 'buildexpression'
I wrote the code below into my view so I can get the list of CarouselViewItem back but Xcode still show an error when doing istOfCarouselItem.append(
func getCarouselItems(_ listOfItems: [String]) -> [CarouselViewItem] {
    var listOfCarouselItem: [CarouselViewItem] = []
        
    ForEach(Array(listOfItems.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, item in
        listOfCarouselItem.append(CarouselViewItem(id: index, content: {
            ZStack{
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15.0)
                    .fill(Color.red)
                Text(listOfItems[index])
            }
        }))
    }
        
    return listOfCarouselItem
}

and the CarouselViewItem is defined as below:
struct CarouselViewItem: View, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    @ViewBuilder var content: any View
     
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            AnyView(content)
        }
    }
}

Any idea ?

ForEach is used to create a group of View. You are just appending to an array of views, this doesn't work. In general, adding View items into an array is usually not a good idea.

I am pretty sure you can’t create and return an array of views like that and even if you can shouldn’t the array be declared as [any View]?

You should remove any from of “any View” or “AnyView” from your toolset, ViewBuilder should use “some View” or a concrete type. Also this error is always a typo so comment out sections and simplify code to find the typo

ForEach is used to generating view not for appending the views into a list. You can use for-in loop to append a view into an array. Here is the updated code
func getCarouselItems(_ listOfItems: [String]) -> [CarouselViewItem] {
    var listOfCarouselItem: [CarouselViewItem] = []

    for (index, item) in listOfItems.enumerated() {
        let carouselItem = CarouselViewItem(id: index) {
            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15.0)
                    .fill(Color.red)
                Text(item)
            }
        }
        listOfCarouselItem.append(carouselItem)
    }
    return listOfCarouselItem
}

Here is the CarouselViewItem definition
struct CarouselViewItem: View, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    @ViewBuilder var content: () -> any View

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            content()
        }
    }
}

